# Push/Pop vs Mov with Registers

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

In x86_64 (assembling with nasm on Linux) my intuition tells me that `rax` would have the same contents after both (1) and (2).

```
push qword 11               ; (1) Works!
pop rax

;mov rax, qword 11          ; (2) Doesn't Work!
```

But (1) works just fine and (2) makes my program segfault.  What is going on here?

Comment: What about simply `mov rax, 11`?

Comment: Have tried that too - same problem.

Comment: Well, NASM v 2.10 (Mar 2012) seems to assemble this into `mov eax, 11`, despite there being `bits 64` before it. However, YASM v 1.3.0 (Aug 2014) does assemble it correctly. Check out a newer version of NASM or try YASM instead.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: `mov eax, 11` is what you want anyway, unless you're going to patch the binary with a constant that doesn't have the upper 32bits zeroed.  Any write to a 32bit register zeros the upper 32, so `mov r/m64, imm32` (with a sign-extended imm32), or worse `mov r64, imm64` just waste insn bytes if your constant is `11`.  NASM knows that, and chooses the shorter encoding (`mov r32, imm32` with a one-byte opcode that includes 3 bits for the dest register.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Forgot that, thanks for reminding! `mov rax, 0x1122334455667788` assembles into a 64-bit instruction.

Answer (score 5):

`push imm8` / `pop` is a compact way (3 bytes) to put a small integer in a register.  Inefficient but exactly the same effect as `mov eax,11` or `mov rax, strict qword 11`.  *[Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/132985#132985)*

The net result should be the same, except for leaving an `11` in stack space.  They of course have different machine code, so if this is shellcode then the `mov rax, 11` version include some `00` bytes which would terminate a `strcpy` or similar buffer overflow.

Note that NASM optimizes `mov rax, 11` to `mov eax, 11` because it's shorter and has *exactly* the same effect on the architectural state (registers values and memory, other than RIP of course since it's a shorter instruction.)

If you wanted to patch the binary later with different constants, or if you were aiming for code alignment, you might use an override `strict qword 11` to force the instruction to be encoded as `mov r64, imm64`, the REX.W version of `mov eax, 11`.

YASM doesn't do code-size optimizations that change the operand-size attribute of an instruction, but NASM by default does.

`mov rax, qword 11` does *not* force it, it mostly just sets the size of that operand, not the encoding.  e.g. `mov [rdi], qword 11` is an unconventional way to write `mov qword [rdi], 11`, where a size specifier is necessary somewhere because neither operand is a register that implies a size.

---

When I first posted this answer, I didn't test `mov rax, strict qword 11`.  See also re: the 3 ways a `mov` of an immediate `11` into a register could be encoded which do show syntax and machine code for that:

- [Why NASM on Linux changes registers in x86_64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596247/why-nasm-on-linux-changes-registers-in-x86-64-assembly/48597025#48597025)
- [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64) (AT&T syntax, but the supported machine code instructions are the same.)
- [Hex machine code for mov immediate to 64-bit register doesn't have a REX.W prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338052/hex-machine-code-for-mov-immediate-to-64-bit-register-doesnt-have-a-rex-w-prefi/72338230#72338230)

```
; test-encoding.asm
    ...
    mov  eax, 11
    mov  rax, qword 11

    push qword 11   ; yasm rejects this with "invalid size for operand 1"
                    ; probably because there is no  push imm64  encoding
    pop rax

    ; push  dword [rsi]  ; no such instruction
    push  word [rsi]
```

```
nasm -felf64 test-encoding.asm
objconv -fyasm  test-encoding.o /dev/stdout

    mov     eax, 11                                 ; 0042 _ B8, 0000000B
    mov     eax, 11                                 ; 0047 _ B8, 0000000B
    push    11                                      ; 004C _ 6A, 0B
    pop     rax                                     ; 004E _ 58
```

objconv is Agner Fog's very nice disassembler.  See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki for links.  `objdump -Mintel -d` works, too, but doesn't have helpful comments about potential problems.

In 64bit mode, the default operand size for `push` is a qword.  So the `push imm8` sign-extended-constant encoding only takes two bytes.

---

So the push/pop encoding is shorter.  If the rest of your code is buggy, **possibly there's a problem that only manifests with different code alignment**, or different padding?

---

[Intel's manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push) says that the operand size can be overridden with a `REX.W` prefix or the operand-size prefix (`66H`), but that's not actually true.  REX.W=0 can't change the operand-size to 32-bit, the operand-size of push/pop is 64-bit by default in 64-bit mode (and REX prefixes aren't available in other modes).  So REX.W=1 isn't *overriding* it.

In 64-bit mode, the only 2 sizes for push/pop are 16 and 64-bit.  (And in other modes, 16 or 32-bit).
The 2 sizes for the immediate are sign-extended 8-bit or 32-bit.  (Or 16-bit for 16-bit operand-size.)

NASM, YASM, and GNU `as` all correctly refuse to assemble `push dword [rsi]` or `pushl (%rsi)`.  Using `db 0x40` to manually insert a REX.W=0 prefix ahead of `push qword [rsi]` makes disassemblers choke on it.

Actually running `push rdx` on real hardware, with REX.W=0 (`db 0x40`) or REX.W=1 (`db 0x48`) gives identical results: a 64-bit push of the full register, decrementing rsp by 8.  (Tested on Sandybridge when I wrote this answer, and later also on Skylake or Core 2, I forget which I was using when answering *[How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-push-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-specif)* which covers the same details.)

This wouldn't be the first time the Intel manual is wrong. :/  The table of valid encodings in the same [entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push) in the instruction-set reference does confirm that `push r32` and `push r/m32` are Not Encodeable in 64-bit mode, only compat / legacy modes, but the phrasing of the description section saying that a REX.W can override the operand-size is definitely wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and pointer to some good tools @Peter!  When I get time, I'll play around with the different assemblers and see what opcodes result.  I'll mark this as accepted once I figure out what's going on in my code!